# Strange Put Json form data (Jquery Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

i'm trying do a PUT request with JQUERY AJAX with a object with other object inside, the code is like:

```js
var dataSend = {field1: 'this', field2:'thisone'};
var insideData = {name: 'myName', age:'18'};

data.inside = insideData;

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8888/api/datas",
  type: "PUT",
  data: dataSend,
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {....
```

I'm just waiting for a data in server side (Node.js) with something like:

```
{
    field1: 'this', 
    field2:'thisone',
    inside: {name: 'myName', age:'18'}
}
```

But instead, i recieved:

```
{
    field1: 'this', 
    field2:'thisone',
    'inside[name]': 'myName',
    'inside[age]': '18'
}
```

**So, what i'm doing wrong?**
**How can get the insideData for use in my Server Side?**

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
var dataSend = {field1: 'this', field2:'thisone','inside':{name: 'myName', age:'18'}};
```

or:

```
var insideData = {name: 'myName', age:'18'};
var dataSend = {field1: 'this', field2:'thisone','inside':insideData};
```

Comment: I try it but is the same result.

Comment: then use JSON.stringify()  to convert it to a proper json

Comment: I try but the data is strangest, it send an ['jsonString', '']