# Get JSON data from form array fields expressjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have some fields that are named such as `name[last][abbreviation]` etc.  I'm using jQuery to post this data.  When I get this data on the server (nodejs), I'd like to have this in an object format, such as:

```
 {
   name: {
     last: {
       abbreviation: 'a'
     }
   }
 }
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by `array fields` here?

Answer (score 0):

Server side you can do something like this.

```
var obj_data = JSON.parse(json_data);
```

obj_data will then be a normal javascript object.  The reverse is JSON.stringify(obj_data) which will convert a javascript object back into a string.

Comment: So, I'm assign this field name to a 'field' property when it's posted.  It's coming back like `{field: 'name[last][abbreviation]'}`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly my same Question: [Strange Put Json form data (Jquery Ajax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452122/strange-put-json-form-data-jquery-ajax/37452388#37452388)

The problem is not in Express is in the Fron End, if you see browser send the headers of child Object like an array child[field], so real question is: how to managge the child data in the Server side?